# Foreign keys and pagination

Tags: php, sql, primary-key

This is my pagination script:

```
    <?php
/***********************************
 * PhpMyCoder Paginator            *
 * Created By PhpMyCoder           *
 * 2010 PhpMyCoder                 *
 * ------------------------------- *
 * You may use this code as long   *
 * as this notice stays intact and *
 * the proper credit is given to   *
 * the author.                     *
 ***********************************/
?> 
 <head>
     <title> Pagination Test - Created By PhpMyCoder</title>
        <style type="text/css">
   #nav { font: normal 13px/14px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; margin: 2px 0; }
   #nav a { background: #EEE; border: 1px solid #DDD; color: #000080; padding: 1px 7px; text-decoration: none; }
   #nav strong { background: #000080; border: 1px solid #DDD; color: #FFF; font-weight: normal; padding: 1px 7px; }
   #nav span { background: #FFF; border: 1px solid #DDD; color: #999; padding: 1px 7px; }
  </style>
    </head>
     <?php
   //Require the file that contains the required classes
   include("pmcPagination.php");

   //PhpMyCoder Paginator
   $paginator = new pmcPagination(20, "page");

   //Connect to the database
   mysql_connect("localhost","root","PASSWORD");
   //Select DB
   mysql_select_db("tvguide");

   //Select only results for today and future
   $result = mysql_query("SELECT programme, channel, airdate, expiration, episode, setreminder FROM epdata1 where airdate >= now() order by expiration GROUP BY airdate");
   //You can also add reuslts to paginate here
   mysql_data_seek($queryresult,0) ;
           while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
   {
    $paginator->add(new paginationData($row['programme'],
               $row['channel'],
               $row['airdate'],
               $row['expiration'],
               $row['episode'],
               $row['setreminder']));
   }
  ?>
        <?php
   //Show the paginated results
   $paginator->paginate ();
  ?><? include("pca-footer1.php"); ?>
        <?php
   //Show the navigation
   $paginator->navigation();      
  ?>
```

However, I have two tables in this, and they are epdata1 (where the airtimes for my show House M.D. are) and housemdep plus the setreminder table.

How can I use foreign keys in relation to this? I'm not sure if this will work for my script, but am willing to try.

What I would like to do is to select certain episodes from the table housemdep
(episodes of the show) and if any are selected it shows them as this:

```
House M.D. showing on Channel 1 June 6th - 8:00pm "Wilson" Set Reminder
House M.D. showing on Channel 1 June 7th - 1:30am "Wilson" Set Reminder
House M.D. showing on Channel 1 June 7th - 12:55pm "House's Head" Set Reminder
```

or like this, if I have not selected an episode from the row:

```
House M.D. showing on Channel 1 June 7th - 8:00pm "House's Head" Set Reminder
House M.D. showing on Channel 1 June 8th - 9:00pm  Set Reminder
House M.D. showing on Channel 1 June 9th - 2:30pm Set Reminder
House M.D. showing on Channel 1 June 7th - 8:00pm "Que Sera Sera" Set Reminder
```

Foreign keys and relationship of interlinked tables are new to me, if anyone could help I'd appreciate this.

Also, I'm trying to get it like this for my programme (this is how the code should render if you clicked on View Source in your browser):

```
<tr><td><b><a href="housemd.php">House M.D.</a></b></td><td>showing on <a href="channel/1"><i>Channel 1</i></a></td><td>June 9th - 7:00pm</td><td><b>"<a href="episodes/714790">House's Head</a>"</b></td><td><img src="reminder.gif" height="16" width="22"> <a href="reminder.php" alt="Set a reminder" target="_top">Set Reminder</a></td></tr>
```

**House M.D.**showing on *Channel 1*June 10th - 12:25am**"House's Head"** Set Reminder
**House M.D.**showing on *Channel 1*June 10th - 12:55pm  Set Reminder
**House M.D.**showing on *Channel 1*June 10th - 9:00pm**"Wilson"** Set Reminder
**House M.D.**showing on *Channel 1*June 11th - 1:30am**"Wilson"** Set Reminder
**House M.D.**showing on *Channel 1*June 11th - 8:00pm**"Living The Dream"** Set Reminder
**House M.D.**showing on *Channel 1*June 12th - 7:00pm  Set Reminder

I've tried some of what Google suggested on foreign keys in another version of this script (this is a clone of the original on my localhost server running Apache and PHP 5.28/MySQL), but am not sure how to implement this.

Thanks.

Comment: what are you having trouble with? Do you need help with the database query connecting the tables together through foreign keys? If not, then join the tables together and see what your pagination does. best way to learn is to try. make changes to fix.

Also, that isn't really the best way to paginate a query. If your query has like 10k results, it will buffer all of those results and then you are using only 20 (or whatever your per page value is) from that buffered list of 10k. It is generally better to use the mysql keyword LIMIT to just have your query return only the number of rows needed.

Comment: I am having trouble using the database query connecting the tables together through foreign keys, that's the gist of it.
As for my pagination script that shows 20 rows per script, it is a free script that I am using ;)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're saying, you're looking to have the SQL query join two tables, and based on the database's response, display rows somewhat differently depending on whether rows are found in one table or another.

You're right in that joins are what you're looking for, it just sounds like you need to get to know the types of joins. INNER JOINs are for situations where you're expecting rows from one table to always correspond to rows in another table (and to never return rows if they don't have corresponding rows). LEFT JOINs are for situations where you're querying data from one table, but you may or may not have corresponding rows available in another table.

For example: A person will always have parents (INNER JOIN).

```
SELECT
  person.id,
  relative.id
FROM
  person
INNER JOIN
  relative
ON
  person.biological_mother_id = relative.id
```

In this example, rows will be returned where both person.id and relative.id will have values, otherwise, the database will not return rows because those rows don't match the INNER JOIN criteria.

However, a person will not always have a pet (LEFT JOIN).

```
SELECT
  person.id,
  pet.id
FROM
  person
LEFT JOIN
  pets
ON
  person.id = pets.owner_id
```

In this case, rows can be returned where person.id has a value, but pet.id has no value (NULL value, in some cases). This is because the LEFT JOIN does not put a constraint on the rows returned like the INNER JOIN, it says instead that the "left" or "primary" table can return row values, but it is optional for the "right" or "secondary" tables to return values.

It is in this way we use relational databases to ask questions about the relationships between tables. If you perform the above pet query, and pet.id is returned null, you know that that person has no pets.